# Add comma if numbers contains 5 or 6 digits

Tags: javascript, jquery

My input field contains multiple numbers and every numbers contains 5 or 6 digts  like this:

```
10883 500643 10886 502814
```

and when user keypress and if user press space I want `automatically` add comma (,)  between them.

How can i achieve this ?! Can anyone please help me :)

This is my code so far, it will add comma only after each numbers which contains 5 digits :

JavaScript:

```
<script>
    <input name="CustomerNumber" id="CustomerNumber">

    $("#CustomerNumber").on('input', function () {

    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/,/g, '').replace(/(\d{5}(?!$))/g, "$1,"));

    });
</script>
```

OutPut will be come like this user enter first 5 digits comma will automatic added than user enter 6 digits comma automatic added and so on :

```
10883,500643,10886,502814
```

Comment: you want comma after every number or just after 5 or 6 ??

Comment: @DevsiOdedra  just after 5 or 6 :)

Comment: Could you please also include your output here. As you given input

Comment: @SourabhSomani just did :)

Comment: Okay means when user will keypress and if he press space you want comma

Comment: @SourabhSomani yes only after 5 or 6 digits

Comment: Okay got your point now :)

Comment: So first comma after 5th and later on every 6 digits?

Comment: @Justinas it could be 6th first and than 5th so im lookin for some conditions check length of each numbers and if length== 5 add comma and if length== 6 add comma

Answer (score 0):

This will add a comma after minimum 5 and max 6 digits. If number of digits are less than 5, it won't add any comma even if there's a space. And if they are more than 6 digits, it will automatically add a comma after every 6 digits.

```
$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/,/g, '').replace(/(\d{5,6})/g, "$1,")
```

Comment: im talking about multiple numbers which every one of them contains 5 or 6 digits

Comment: It'll work with multiple numbers. For example if the input is `10883 500643 10886 502814 1111 23532 678 897643 98787987964654654648 54664` , the output will be `10883, 500643, 10886, 502814, 1111 23532, 678 897643, 987879,879646,546546,48 54664,`

Comment: when i enter 500643 , out will be 50064,3

Comment: or when i enter 10883 500643 10886 out put will be like this : 108835,006431,0886

Comment: According to your above comments need to check input's length.
`if ($(this).val().length == 6)
            {
                $(this).val().replace(/,/g, '').replace(/ /g, '').replace(/(\d{5})/g, "$1,");
            }
            else if ($(this).val().length > 6){
                $(this).val().replace(/,/g, '').replace(/ /g, '').replace(/(\d{6})/g, "$1,");
            }`

Comment: there is only one input field and when i write 10883 500643 length of value input will be 11 not 5 or 6